# Laravel db table can't throw variable from controller to page file

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have problem with variable.

```
$data_news is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $data_news }} with {{ $data_news ?? '' }}
```

Controller take data from db and return view. Next in web.php Routing throw variable from Controller to page file

Controller Code

```
        <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class NewsController extends Controller
    {
        public function home(){
            $data_news = DB::table('post')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->limit(6)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
    
            return view('Pages.home')->with('Pages', $data_news);
        }
    }
```

view page code

```
                    @foreach ($data_news as $news)
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-52"><img src="strony/assets/img/newspaper-solid.svg" style="width: 100px;">
                    <p style="text-align: center;">{{ $news->title }}</p>
                    <p style="text-align: left;"><br>{{ $news->text }}</p>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

And web.php Route

> Route::resource('Pages/home', 'NewsController');

How can I fix this problem

Comment: You pass it to the view as `$Pages`in your with function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass it to the view as $Pages instead of $data_news.
The first parameter for the with function is the variable name

```
return view('Pages.home')->with('data_news', $data_news);
```

Comment: @patryk6654 where is your route for the home action? Or is it the resource index ?

Comment: in web.php file and it looks like this `Route::resource('Pages/home', 'NewsController');`

Comment: That route is not correct. If you want to use resource controllers, you should read the documentation. Note that variable names and table names are very important if you use these. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers . It looks to me like you want to define custom  routes...  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Answer (score 0):

Use compact

```
public function home(){
        $data_news = DB::table('post')
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->limit(6)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

        return view('Pages.home', compact('data_news'));
    }


@if($data_news)
  @foreach ($data_news as $news)
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-52"><img src="strony/assets/img/newspaper-solid.svg" style="width: 100px;">
        <p style="text-align: center;">{{ $news->title }}</p>
        <p style="text-align: left;"><br>{{ $news->text }}</p>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: In the question the `with()` function is used. Maybe stick with that. and explain what  your answer does so people can learn from it

Comment: @patryk6654 this should work. the compact function returns an array `['data_news' => $data_news]`. this is passed to the view. So `$data_news` should be available with this code